# Yocto: add musl library giving build error

Tags: yocto, musl

In my rootfs I need `musl` support. I added `musl` in my `local.conf` by adding:

```
TCLIBC = "musl"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " musl"
```

built `core-image-full-cmdline`. I am getting error like below

```
> +++
> 
> make[4]: Leaving directory
> '/home/user/yocto/poky_thud/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-cross-x86_64/2.31.1-r0/git/build.x86_64-linux.x86_64-poky-linux-musl/gas/po'
> 
> Makefile:1260: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
> 
> make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
> 
> make[3]: Leaving directory
> '/home/user/yocto/poky_thud/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-cross-x86_64/2.31.1-r0/git/build.x86_64-linux.x86_64-poky-linux-musl/gas'
> 
> Makefile:808: recipe for target 'all' failed
> 
> make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
> 
> make[2]: Leaving directory
> '/home/user/yocto/poky_thud/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-cross-x86_64/2.31.1-r0/git/build.x86_64-linux.x86_64-poky-linux-musl/gas'
> 
> Makefile:4865: recipe for target 'all-gas' failed
> 
> make[1]: *** [all-gas] Error 2
> 
> make[1]: Leaving directory
> '/home/user/yocto/poky_thud/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-cross-x86_64/2.31.1-r0/git/build.x86_64-linux.x86_64-poky-linux-musl'
> 
> Makefile:849: recipe for target 'all' failed
> 
> make: *** [all] Error 2
> 
> ERROR: oe_runmake failed
> 
> WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
> 
> ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at
> /home/user/yocto/poky_thud/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/binutils-cross-x86_64/2.31.1-r0/temp/log.do_compile.19779)
> 
> +++
```

Is this method wrong to build musl?
Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thank you.

Comment: Check the log that was generated(log.do_compile.19779) it should give you some idea what the issue is.

Comment: Yes, I have pasted those logs from log file, in the issue description while posting this question. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Able to resolve the issue. Was doing an incremental build and glibc was selected earlier. A full clean and rebuild solved the issue.